# Need assistance with creating a procedure in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to create an edit or add procedure in mysql and running into an error. Here's the code:

```
CREATE DEFINER = CURRENT_USER PROCEDURE `SalesAddOrEdit`(u_id int, u_prodid VARCHAR(255), u_datepurchase DATE, u_price VARCHAR(255), u_customer_1 VARCHAR(255), u_paid_1 VARCHAR(255))

BEGIN
        IF uid = 0 then
    INSERT INTO sales(prodid, datepurchase, price, customer_1, paid_1, shipped_1)
    
    VALUES (u_prodid, u_datepurchase, u_price, u_customer_1, u_paid_1, u_shipped_1)
    Else
    UPDATE sales
    SET prodid = u_prodid,
    SET datepurchase = u_purchasedate,
    SET price = u_price,
    SET customer_1 = u_customer_1,
    SET paid_1 = u_paid_1,
    SET shipped_1 = u_shipped_1
    WHERE uid = u_id;
End If;

END;
```

I've tried multiple method such as Declaring the variables using DECLARE, Using @(variables) to no available. Error I'm getting is:

1064 - you have an error in your sql syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO sales(prodid, datepurchase, price, customer_1, paid_1, shipped_1)' at line 5.

Tested this code as well:

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE SalesAddOrEdit()

BEGIN

DECLARE u_id int;
DECLARE u_prodid VARCHAR(255);
DECLARE u_datepurchase DATE;
DECLARE u_price VARCHAR(255); 
DECLARE u_customer_1 VARCHAR(255); 
DECLARE u_paid_1 VARCHAR(255);

        IF uid = 0 THEN
    INSERT INTO sales(prodid, datepurchase, price, customer_1, paid_1, shipped_1)
    
    VALUES (u_prodid, u_datepurchase, u_price, u_customer_1, u_paid_1, u_shipped_1)
    Else
    UPDATE sales
    SET prodid = u_prodid;
    SET datepurchase = u_purchasedate;
    SET price = u_price;
    SET customer_1 = u_customer_1;
    SET paid_1 = u_paid_1;
    SET shipped_1 = u_shipped_1;
    WHERE uid = u_id;
End if;


END; //

DELIMITER   ;
```

Right at the Update sections; I've also tried:

```
UPDATE sales
SET prodid = u_prodid,datepurchase = u_purchasedate,price = u_price,customer_1 = u_customer_1,paid_1 = u_paid_1,shipped_1 = u_shipped_1
WHERE uid = u_id;
```

Comment: IF needs THEN. Each statement needs proper termination. Multi-statement block needs delimiter reassign. Each variable (except UDV) must be declared before its using.

Comment: Roses are red, violets are blue, I think you're missing an `end if`, aren't you? And semi-colons here and there too.

Comment: same error with adding end if, adding semi-colon after where statement.

Comment: Why are you using a procedure for this?

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax for `update` only uses one `set` clause:

```
UPDATE sales
    SET prodid = u_prodid,
        datepurchase = u_purchasedate,
        price = u_price,
        customer_1 = u_customer_1,
        paid_1 = u_paid_1,
        shipped_1 = u_shipped_1
    WHERE uid = u_id;
```

Comment: Tried that also.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE SalesAddOrEdit()
BEGIN
    DECLARE d_uid int;
    DECLARE d_prodid VARCHAR(255);
    DECLARE d_datepurchase DATE;
    DECLARE d_price VARCHAR(255);
    
    DECLARE d_customer_1 VARCHAR(255); 
    DECLARE d_paid_1 VARCHAR(255); 
    DECLARE d_shipped_1 VARCHAR(255); 

    IF d_uid = 0 Then
            INSERT INTO sales(prodid, datepurchase, price, customer_1, paid_1, shipped_1)
    VALUES 
        (d_prodid, d_datepurchase, d_price, d_customer_1, d_paid_1, d_shipped_1);
    Else
        UPDATE sales
        SET prodid = d_prodid,  datepurchase = d_datepurchase,  price = d_price,    customer_1 = d_customer_1, paid_1 = d_paid_1,   shipped_1 = d_shipped_1
        WHERE uid = d_uid;
    End If;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```